# Volume of a cone that is hollow in the middle

Tags: volume

I've got this problem:
I have a cone (cone $A$) with a radius $8$ and a height of $12$. Now lets say that cone $A$ has a thickness of $2$. This thickness can be found from the bottom and inward and from the sides inward as well. I need to find the volume of the shell that is remaining. I do not yet know the height of the middle cone, only its radius. I've attached a look-alike picture to help give an idea. Any help is appreciated!

Imagine it like this, but with the cone in the middle being the thickness ($2$) inwards (up inside the other cone):

[image]

Comment: you can find out those dimensions by similar triangles. the radius of the smaller cone is 2. use similar triangles to find the height.

Comment: You do not need to know the height of the inner cone to find its volume.  It is similar, which means that all corresponding measurements (e.g. radius and height) will have the same proportionality.

Comment: I assume the radius of the inner cone, which you know, is about $4.26$?